# How to select records from last 2 minutes in my Crystal Report

Tags: email, time, crystal-reports

I am creating a dynamic email burst report for an error message table.  I want to send the report every two minutes, but only send the records added to the table within the last 2 minutes.  I'm having trouble writing my report parameter to do this, if in fact this is the proper way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a filter in your parsed query to your report like this (In SQL Server):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
  AND (DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreationDate, GETDATE()) <= 120)
```

But if you want to use it in a formula inside of your report you can use something like this formula:

```
Datediff(s, {yourTable.CreationDate}, CurrentDateTime)
```

Comment: This is what I wound up with:

({T_SEND.Time} >=dateadd('m',-2,currentdate) and {T_SEND.Time}<=currentdate)

It doesn't appear to work, and the formula you wrote gives me an error when I try to save